# How to make a button float right in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the Add Server button to move to the far right side of the screen. Since float:right does not exist in React, what's the best way to go about doing this?

I made a wrapper called serverNavButtonWrapper tried adding padding to the left but this seems a bit hacky. I also tried adding a wrapper around both h3 titles then did flex-grow: 1 but this didn't work and ending up squishing them into columns. I would appreciate your help!

```
<div className={classes.serverNav}>
      <h3 className={classes.title}>Current Servers</h3>
      <h3 className={classes.title}>All Servers</h3>

      <div className={classes.serverNavButtonWrapper}>
        <Button
          className={classes.serverNavButton}
          variant="outlined"
          size="medium"
          color="default"
        >
          <AddIcon /> Server
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[preview of current render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMqXS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the margin to auto on a flex item, it will grow to the maximum available space. So the following will do the trick:

```
.serverNav {
  display: flex;
}

.serverNavButtonWrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Or, if you don't need the wrapper anymore:

```
.serverNav {
  display: flex;
}

.serverNavButton {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` property is primary the CSS property.

You can pass the stylesheet to the React components via the `style` attribute, e.g.:

```js
<p style={{fontSize: "12px"}}>Text</div>
```

Two curly brackets are there because the argument type of `style` is an object and you are initializing it there.

So your code should look like this:

```js
<div className={classes.serverNav}>
      <h3 className={classes.title}>Current Servers</h3>
      <h3 className={classes.title}>All Servers</h3>

      <div className={classes.serverNavButtonWrapper}>
        <Button
          className={classes.serverNavButton}
          variant="outlined"
          size="medium"
          color="default"
          style={{float: "right"}}
        >
          <AddIcon /> Server
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
```